# AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'create_mute'

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm just trying to use create_mute with Twython. But I keep getting this error and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Python 2.7+ just running it locally out of my terminal to see if it works.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import sys

## data from account (these are filled in properly, in my file) ###

APP_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
APP_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    target = sys.argv[1]
else:
    target = raw_input("User to mute: ")

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

try:
    twitter.create_mute(screen_name=target)

except TwythonError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: have you tried verifying your credentials to see if auth was successful? [link](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/basic_usage.html#user-information)

Comment: What's the Twython version you have installed? (`print twython.__version__`). I've confirmed that `create_mute` is not present in 3.2.0, but is present in the current version, 3.3.0.

Comment: It was indeed, the twython version. Well...at least it wasn't a super yak shaving session.